# Passport Saml Loop

Tags: node.js, passport.js, mean-stack, adfs

I'm trying to make a ADFS identification with Passport-Saml.js in a nodejs/angularjs project.

1. When I'm connecting to my Web Site I'm correctly redirected to my ADFS portal.
2. ADFS portal, after authentication correctly redirects to callback.
3. Then the callback loop.

[Chrome console when it's looping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYhr3.png*)

That my route (server.js):

```
app.post('/login/callback',
 function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('before');
  passport.authenticate('saml', function (err, user, info){
    console.log('good');

})(req, res, next);

});
```

I think it stops working at passport.authenticate('saml',function (err,user, info){ because "before" output message can be seen in the console but nor the "good" as seen in the screenshot. [The console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLLF0.png)

And my passport configuration (/config/passport.js):

```
var
 fs = require('fs')
 , passport = require('passport')
 , SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy
;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
 done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
 done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
{
  entryPoint: 'https://logon.XXX.com/adfs/ls/',
  issuer: 'urn:backpack-test',
  callbackUrl: ' https://backpack-test.XXX.com/login/callback',
  cert: 'MIIC6D...,
  authnContext:         'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password',
  //acceptedClockSkewMs: -1,
  identifierFormat: null,
  //signatureAlgorithm: 'sha256'
},
function (profile, done) {
 return done(null,
  {
        upn: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn'],
        // e.g. if you added a Group claim
        group: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group']
    });
    }
    ));

module.exports = passport;
```

I suspect my settings might be incorrect but is there any verbose log of passport-Saml in order to narrow down my troubleshooting.

Comment: Could you figure out what is the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe is this problem:
[Check this bug](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml/issues/128)

Just add the body-parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

It worked for me. Maybe it can help others...

Comment: Had the same loop issue. Adding bodyParser solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to perseus, I add just a note. I was using:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
```

and I thought it was enough, but it wasn't, because body parser was ignoring urlencoded requests. So I had to specify both:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```